# Existence and uniqueness of solution to minimization problem over convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

> Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be nonempty, closed and convex.
> Fix some $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider:
> $$ \min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{C}}\Vert\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{x}\Vert $$
>
> **(i)** Show that the problem has a solution
>
> **(ii)** Show that the solution is the unique global minimizer

---

For **(i)**, I have been able to show that $f(\mathbf{x}):=\Vert\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{x}\Vert$ is a convex function. Let $\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}\in\mathcal{C}$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(\alpha\mathbf{p}+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{q})
&= \Vert \mathbf{z} - (\alpha\mathbf{p}+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{q})\Vert \\
&= \Vert \mathbf{z} - \alpha\mathbf{p}-(1-\alpha)\mathbf{q} \Vert \\
&= \Vert \alpha\mathbf{z}+(1-\alpha)\mathbf{z}-\alpha\mathbf{p}-(1-\alpha)\mathbf{q}\Vert \\
&= \Vert \alpha(\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{p})+(1-\alpha)(\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{q}) \Vert \\
&\leq \Vert \alpha(\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{p}) \Vert\ + \ \Vert (1-\alpha)(\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{q}) \Vert \\
&= \alpha\Vert\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{p}\Vert\ +\ (1-\alpha)\Vert\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{q}\Vert \\
&= \alpha f(\mathbf{p}) + (1-\alpha)f(\mathbf{q})
\end{align*}
$$

Since $f$ is convex and $\mathcal{C}$ is convex, I have the following necessary and sufficient conditions for optimality (from my lecture notes):

> **Necessary condition**: *any local optimal point is stationary*.
>
> **Sufficient condition**: *if $f$ is convex, any stationary point is global optimal*.

So I think that it suffices to show the existence of a stationary point of $f$. Since $f$ is convex, the sufficient condition above would mean such a stationary point is a global minimizer, and thus a solution exists. I'm unsure how to proceed at this point, and I feel like I'm missing something elementary.

---

For **(ii)** above, I believe that I would need to show that $f$ is strictly convex. If $f$ is strictly convex, then the minimizer
of
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{C}}{f(\mathcal{x})}
$$
is unique.

---

I would greatly appreciate any hints as to how I could proceed with these problems, particularly **(i)**.

Comment: Existence and uniqueness of a minimizer is one of the  first results in the theory of Hilbert spaces. Using convexity is not the best way of proving this.

Comment: I meant to say using convex functions is not the best way of proving this. Convexity if $C$ is, of course, crucial.